# Swifyjson with tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I m trying to populate my tableview with the json data that i m getting on url using swiftyjson .The problem i m facing is , i m apprehending the city  in the array but when i use it on the table view the data does not show .How can i fix it ?(you could check the data structure of my json  by clicking on the url ).

```
  import UIKit
  import SwiftyJSON
  import  Alamofire



  class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource {
 @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

var data = [String]()
var numberofRows = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Alamofire.request(.GET,  "http://android.goidx.com/search")
        .responseJSON {( response) -> Void in


            if let value = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value)


                for (index,json):(String, JSON) in json {
                    //Do something you want
                    self.numberofRows = json["city"].count


                    let city = json["city"].string! as String

                     self.data.append(city)
                   print(json["city"].stringValue)
                }

    }
    }

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return numberofRows
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as  UITableViewCell

    if data.count != 0 {
    cell.textLabel?.text =  data[indexPath.row]

    }

    return cell
   }




   }
```

Answer (score 1):

After you create your array of cities, you need to reload the table view to refresh the contents

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Also change your datasource, numberOfRowsInSection method to return

```
self.data.count
```

I noticed that the cities key in the json returned does not map to an array.

Comment: From looking at the json, city is not an array so that count will not be correct. Change your numberOfRowsInSection to return self.data.count instead as well.

Comment: Yes ! i did changed it to self.data.count but its not showing in the table view .This is how  the output of the data array when i print it , its giving me multiple arrays .["Other County - Not In Usa"]
["Other County - Not In Usa", "Homestead"]
["Other County - Not In Usa", "Homestead", "Doral"]
["Other County - Not In Usa", "Homestead", "Doral", "Hallandale"]

Comment: also makes sure tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: yes i did connect the tableview to the viewcontroller  already

Comment: Working thanks! this is what i had to do json["city"].stringValue

Comment: Uh looks right to me. You're printing it after every iteration so the array should get larger by 1 each time which it looks like it does. Do you have tableView.reloadData()  just outside the closing scope of that for loop ?